# prototype and TypeScript Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, prototype

I have a button bind to  a function calling another function from a different component to open modal form,  passing as parameters  the costumer name and an icon.

Works fine If It´s is called like:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-customer',
    templateUrl: './customer.component.html',
    providers: [Items]
})

export class Costumers {
    @Input() customerNane

    Constructor() {}

    openDocs() {
         Items.prototype.OpenDocs(this.customerNane, "fa-book")`;
    }
}
```

But, if i have it on the construtor and call it like:

```
constructor(private items: Items) {}

 openDocs() {
    this.items.OpenDocs(this.customerNmane, "fa-book")`;
}
```

Parameters wont't bind.

Much obliged for any explanation!

Update.. items.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { MainService } from '../services/main.service'

var JQuery = require('jquery');


@Component({
    selector: 'app-items',
    templateUrl: './items.component.html'

})


export class Items {
    public Title: string;
    public faAny: string;    

    vTypeList = [

        {
            vIdType: "",
            vDsType: ""
        }
    ]

    constructor(private http: Http, private mainService: MainService) {

    this.GetItemsType();
    }

    GetItemsType() {

        this.http.get('/Items/GetItemsType')
            .subscribe(data => {
                var ObjTp = JSON.parse(data.json());                
                for (var i in ObjTp) {
                    if (ObjTp[i] != null) {
                        this.vTypeList.push(ObjTp[i]);
                    }
                }              

            });

    }   


    OpenDocs(pTitle: string, pFaAny: string) {

        this.Title = pTitle;
        this.faAny = pFaAny;
        JQuery('#docs').modal('show');

    }

    private CloseDocs() {

            JQuery('#docs').css("display", "none");
            JQuery('#docs').modal('hide');

        }

    }
```

and the bind its two way

```
 <h4 ng-model="Title" ><i class="fa {{faAny}}"></i> Add some list: {{Title}}</h4>
```

Comment: You are providing `Item`, not `Items`. But, if these are components as you say, you shouldn't be providing them at all... providing is for services. Is `Items` a service?

Comment: Sorry I´ve misspell it. updating question. To answer yours, Yes and no, as I'm working with `C# MVC Template` and for now, I have one  get on it ` this.http.get('/Items/GetItemsType')`. Guess no.. im not realy using it as a service.

Comment: Can you post what `Items` looks like?

Comment: Updated... i left the `addIems()` and `removeItems()`  out to short it up. Its not a big of a problem  but i realy wonder why...Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 0):

> Parameters wont't bind.

Use an arrow function. Change

```
openDocs() {
    this.items.OpenDocs(this.customerNmane, "fa-book");
}
```

to

```
openDocs = () => {
    this.items.OpenDocs(this.customerNmane, "fa-book");
}
```

## Why

Cause arrow functions ensure correct `this`.

## More

- https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/arrow-functions.html

Comment: No success, i think could  be something with the life cicle or so.. thanks anyway.